# Shared element transition coming with blink

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I have recyclerview on click of its item i'm opening an activity with shared element transition like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActive, EnlargeActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("IMAGE_URL", imageArrayList.get(position).getUrl());
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                holder.iv.setTransitionName(String.valueOf(MainActivity.position + "ZoomImage"));
                ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                        makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActive,
                                holder.iv,
                                ViewCompat.getTransitionName(holder.iv));

                context.startActivity(myIntent, options.toBundle());
```

in activity it has viewpager:

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enlarge);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(null);
    }

    supportPostponeEnterTransition();
```

In viewpager adapter which extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter returning a fragment ProductDetailViewPagerFragment that has an imageview and im loading images like this: (MainActivity.position is position of recyclerview)

```
Picasso.with(getActivity())
            .load(url)
            .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        imageView.setTransitionName(MainActivity.position + "ImageZoom");
                    }

                    getActivity().supportStartPostponedEnterTransition();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        imageView.setTransitionName(MainActivity.position + "ImageZoom");
                    }

                    getActivity().supportStartPostponedEnterTransition();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Instead of calling `setTransitionName` after Picasso load success. Call it when the `ImageView` is created, in your `ViewPager` adapter

Comment: ok trying, what about this: getActivity().supportStartPostponedEnterTransition(); is it not right?

Comment: it's right, postpone and wait for the image load then start again is the right path

Comment: so still i need to "Call it when the ImageView is created, in your ViewPager adapter"?

Comment: No difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should setTransitionName for ViewPager in the second activity. The previous view will be connected with viewPager.
If you call

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    imageView.setTransitionName(MainActivity.position + "ImageZoom");
  }
```

after image load success (or failed), the transition is finished and it will be not working.

Comment: what about this: getActivity().supportStartPostponedEnterTransition(); i have postponed and then when image load start transition